# Problemas para activar Allow Unsafe. No puedo ejecutar unsafe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

Estoy haciendo una web publicada en hostlocal en C# y VisualStudio 2015. Necesito establecer la opción AllowUnsafeBlocks, para una clase que utiliza punteros, pero no puedo. 
Seguro que es una tontería, pero no se verlo y me estoy volviendo loco.

Cuando abro la pagina propiedades del proyecto, en el apartado Compilar, no me sale la opción como debería salir para permitir el código inseguro. Me sale solamente esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el explorador de soluciones, tampoco aparece. ¡¡No lo entiendo !!

La otra opción es añadir en el fichero .csproj las siguientes líneas:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

El problema es que no tengo ningún fichero .csproj ya que es una web creada directamente contra el IIS. Sí que hay un fichero .sln

Los ficheros de configuración que tengo son: website.publishproj, web.config, vwd.webinfo, compilerconfig.json

Alguna sugerencia? Cómo puedo configurar VS 2015 para verlo, o cómo añadir un código en algún fichero de configuración.

Answer (score 1):

No aparece la opcion porque segun veo tienes un `web site` y no un `web project`

[Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/)

sino deberias ver la opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Compiling Unsafe Code in Visual Studio](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSUnsafe.aspx)

Ahora bien a nivel del `web.config` podrias validar esta seccion de configuracion

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler 
            language="c#;cs;csharp" 
            extension=".cs" 
            compilerOptions="/unsafe"
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

valida que tengas `compilerOptions="/unsafe"`

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro. Lo he colocado en web.config y funciona de maravilla.